# How to print QDialog in a PDF file

Tags: python, python-3.x, qpainter

I am trying to print the contents of the QDialog, so that it is saved as a .PDF file, the problem is that the image that is generated is very small

[image]

This is my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QPushButton,QFrame,QDialog
from PyQt5 import QtCore,Qt,QtPrintSupport,QtGui,uic

class Main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("About.ui",self)

        self.resize(800,800)


        printer = QtPrintSupport.QPrinter(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.HighResolution)
        #printer.setPageSize(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.A4)
        printer.setOutputFormat(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.PdfFormat)
        printer.setOutputFileName("preview.pdf")
        printer.setFullPage(False)


        painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        painter.begin(printer)
        screen = self.grab()
        painter.Antialiasing = True
        painter.drawPixmap(100,100,screen)
        painter.end()



app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.resize(800,600)
m.show()
app.exec_()
```

File .ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>475</width>
    <height>312</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background:white;</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>-4</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>481</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background:#010f1c;</string>
   </property>
   <property name="frameShape">
    <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="frameShadow">
    <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
   </property>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="AboutBotonClose">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>450</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>20</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton#MainCerrar{
background:none;
border:0px;
}
</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="icon">
     <iconset>
      <normaloff>../Img/Main/VentanaGeneral/Cerrar.png</normaloff>../Img/Main/VentanaGeneral/Cerrar.png</iconset>
    </property>
    <property name="iconSize">
     <size>
      <width>10</width>
      <height>10</height>
     </size>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>50</x>
     <y>40</y>
     <width>71</width>
     <height>61</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string/>
   </property>
   <property name="pixmap">
    <pixmap>../img/Logo.png</pixmap>
   </property>
   <property name="scaledContents">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>130</x>
     <y>40</y>
     <width>291</width>
     <height>241</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <family>Jura</family>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">border:0px;</string>
   </property>
   <property name="html">
    <string>&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd&quot;&gt;
&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;meta name=&quot;qrichtext&quot; content=&quot;1&quot; /&gt;&lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;
p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
&lt;/style&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body style=&quot; font-family:'Jura'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;&quot;&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-family:'MS Shell Dlg 2'; font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;&quot;&gt;Acerca de:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot;-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-family:'MS Shell Dlg 2'; font-size:10pt;&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;justify&quot; style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-family:'MS Shell Dlg 2'; font-size:8pt;&quot;&gt;School Administration System, es un software de apoyo a las instituciones de educacion de uso libre.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;justify&quot; style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-family:'MS Shell Dlg 2'; font-size:8pt;&quot;&gt;Escrito bajo el lenguaje de programacion Python v 3.6 y la libreria PyQt5 v 5.2rtc1.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;justify&quot; style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-family:'MS Shell Dlg 2'; font-size:8pt;&quot;&gt;Licencia de software libre - 2019&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;justify&quot; style=&quot;-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-family:'MS Shell Dlg 2'; font-size:8pt;&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;justify&quot; style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-family:'MS Shell Dlg 2'; font-size:8pt;&quot;&gt;Autor : Angel Alvarez C.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;justify&quot; style=&quot;-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-family:'MS Shell Dlg 2'; font-size:8pt;&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;justify&quot; style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-family:'MS Shell Dlg 2'; font-size:8pt;&quot;&gt;Fuentes.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;justify&quot; style=&quot;-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-family:'MS Shell Dlg 2'; font-size:8pt;&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;justify&quot; style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-family:'MS Shell Dlg 2'; font-size:8pt;&quot;&gt;Flaticon Icons&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;justify&quot; style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-family:'MS Shell Dlg 2'; font-size:8pt;&quot;&gt;GoogleFonts&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;justify&quot; style=&quot;-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-family:'MS Shell Dlg 2'; font-size:10pt;&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Try to increase the image size using the scale method of the QPainter but if I do this the image is very distorted.
Implement the anti aliasing method to be able to reduce the edges of the image but neither did the image work, it keeps distorting by making it larger

Comment: maybe it has option to set printer resolution, DPI, etc.

Comment: @furas,it is generated with that size in the pdf

Comment: size of PDF may can be not enough. It may need DPI or using inches instead of pixels. I was using `QtPrintSupport` many years ago and I don't remeber details.